# Proof that a scalar field invariant under rotations only depends on norm

Tags: symmetry, rotation, distance, invariants

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued scalar field and $\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ a vector with $r = \sqrt{\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} }$ its norm. Let's say that $f$ is invariant under rotations, such that
\begin{equation}
f(R\mathbf{r}) = f(\mathbf{r}) \ ,
\end{equation}
for all $R$, with $RR^{T} = \mathbb{I}$. Is there a straightforward way to prove that there must exist a function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbf{r}) = h(r)$ for all $\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3$?

I understand that this is almost self-evident. If a function is invariant under rotations then it should only depend on the norm. However, I am not able to prove it more formally without relying on that intuition.

Comment: Have you tried writing down a general function $f(x,y,z)$ in terms of the components and seeing what the consequences of the invariance are?

Comment: In addition to Buzz's suggestion, try finding $g(r,\vartheta,\varphi)=f(r\sin\vartheta\cos\varphi,r\sin\vartheta\sin\varphi,r\cos\vartheta)$ and consider what a rotation does to those; you should be able to derive that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial\varphi}=0$ fairly easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is invariant under rotation, you can always rotate the vector from $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,r)$. Done.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see it. That does it.